# Deny access to files from browser and allow from PHP application

Tags: php, .htaccess

First sorry for my bad English.
I want to hide some files from browser (403 error) and instead of it show my files from a PHP web application. This is my .htaccess file

```
Options All -Indexes
<Files *.txt>
    deny from all
</Files>
<Files *.jpg>
    deny from all
</Files>
```

Is it possible? How can I do it?

Comment: the best way to deny access from browser but be usable in PHP applications, is to simply not have those files accessible at all, in other words, out side of the web directory. eg. If your root web directory is `xxx/html/`, you can have a php file there, and whatever that should not be accessed be put in `xxx/`

Answer (score 0):

```
<Files ~ "\.jpg$">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>
```

Hope this htaccess will do good job for you :)